# When does the gemara learn two stuff from the same פסוק and when not?

Tags: talmud-gemara, bava-kamma

In בבא קמא נח ע' ב the gemara doesn't want to learn two דינים from the same verse, while in many other gemaras (סוטה כט ע' א) the gemara has no such problem.

When does the gemara learn two stuff from the same verse and when not?

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful to include links to the specific gemara in sefaria.com or other sources, so you could get a better answer.

Comment: What part of the gemara in Sota are you referring to? It seems to me that both opinions there only learn the laws from extra words or from logic

Comment: @N.T. another gemara is bava metzia (https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.2.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) which says that "השב תשיבם" teaches us to return a lost object many times, and bava kama (https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.57a.9?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) says it teaches us where to return the object.

Comment: @user24005 Add the detail of the other references to the question please.

Comment: regarding the question of השב תשיבם, its not a question. (https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.31a.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this will be addressed by the commentaries to the talmud. A very useful resource is the sefer Torah Temimah which deals with the Talmudic interpretations on a verse by verse basis. Nevertheless, I will try to give a few general rules as to when one might learn two halachos from one passuk.

The basic idea is that one could only learn the minimum from any specific drasha. So for example, if the Torah says a rule that requires a multiple of something, that means two, which is the minimum of multiple numbers. Similarly, if a word or letter is extra, one can only make one drasha to explain the extra word. Sometimes, however, there are more than one extra words or letters in a passuk, which require multiple drashos. (Many disputes in the Talmud revolve around whether a word or letter is extra or not, see Megillah 2a for example.)

1. Some halachos are derived from the simple meaning of the verse. In this case there is no limitation as to how many halachos can be learned, as they are not drashos per se but simple translations. If in addition to the simple meaning, there is something requiring a drasha in the verse, that would be explained as teaching a halacha additional to those learned from the simple meaning.

A good example is the case the questioner mentioned in his comments. The first halacha comes from a grammatical reading of the word השב ([Rambam there](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.2.9?lang=he&with=Rambam&lang2=he)), and the second comes from the extra word תשיבם. (h/t [Torah Temimah](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.1?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.22.2&lang2=he), which is my go-to sefer for these issues.)

2. If the drasha makes a comparison between two topics, multiple details might be the result of the comparison. This for example is the rule of [אין היקש למחצה](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.22b.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he). Since the Torah compared the two topics, we assume they are similar unless there is a reason otherwise.

3.Sometimes the Gemara will make an *asmachta* or attribute a law to a verse even though the law is not actually derived from the verse. In that case, the law might be attributed to a verse that really teaches a different halacha.

4. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.3a.13?lang=he&p2=Shita_Mekubetzet_on_Bava_Kamma.3a&lang2=he) for the more rare case of two equal drashos being learned from the same passuk and a discussion of the rules.